# Overload Resolution failed in vb for XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

Hello I am trying out using XML for visual basic and I am testing out a feature where when the program loads up. It should be able to load up an XML file as well. If it does manage to load up a file then it displays a message box to the user saying "this works", if not then a different box appears saying "this doesn't work". This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim doc As New DOMDocument60  'Creates 'doc', a new DOM object
    doc.async = False       'Sets some properties on 'doc'. Leave these as-is
    doc.validateOnParse = False
    doc.resolveExternals = False
    doc.load("database.xml")
    If doc.load Then
        MessageBox.Show("This is working")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("File is not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

However there is a problem with the "If doc.load Then" Code because the load part is underlined and it gives me the error of "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'load' accepts this number of arguments.

I don't what I should do in order to fix this. Please help, thank you

Comment: `doc.load` is a `function`. Set a success/failure boolean when you call `doc.load("database.xml")`, then make your `if` statement based on the boolean.

Comment: Tip: put your mouse at the end of the .Load function and type (.. it will show you want it wants... Or select the .LOad text function and press F1

Comment: Are you sure this a `vb.net`? For it seems more like `vba`

Comment: Can you include code for the `load` function in the `DOMDocument60` class? Does it return a value?